# GitHub PRs reviewers reset to 2 after merge

Tags: github

After I merge a pull request in GitHub, the minimum number of requested reviewers for that branch in pull requests automatically is changed back to 2, even if I change it before.

Edited the setup of the branch, but the setup is changed after every merge.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.